# Set image to fit canvas correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I cant seem to fit the image correctly in the canvas a bit is being cut in the first example:

https://jsfiddle.net/kdichev/qqzjtogp/

Here i did it correctly with css but i cant seem to implement this into the first example its because of the javascript code is drawing it a bit off.

https://jsfiddle.net/kdichev/x28wdq47/

```
 // draw all targets on the canvas
for (var i = 0; i < targets.length; i++) {
    var t = targets[i];
    t.width = t.image.width;
    t.height = t.image.height;
    ctx.drawImage(t.image, t.x, t.y);
}
```